override gitlab runners config.toml
We have this config.toml as an example
 [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "python:3"
    memory = "8129m"
    cpus = "6"
    privileged = false

Now, we would like to understand if we can "override" memory or cpus using the value provided in the .gitlab-ci.yaml so that the runners that gets spun up have different memory/cpu ?

Values defined in your .gitlab-ci.yml are superior to those defined in your /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml.
Your example memory + cpu values are only used, if you dont set them in your jobs .gitlab-ci.yml.
The advantage of this behaviour is to set a "default ressource pool" to your runners, except you want one of your jobs with more or less ressources according to your project.

Hello @kekw - we have requirement with respect to different jobs, for example, we have nvidia gpu value set for one job and we have to set different nvidia gpu value for different job. These nvidia gpu also depends on the memory+cpu (small vs med vs large) based jobs. So, how can we override those.

You probably want to create one runner pro respective job(small;med;large). After that you assign your job to the runner which suits best your needs according to required ressources.

It is also important to know, if you use a docker-runner or a kubernetes-runner? For docker-runners see my last answer, but if you use kubernetes, you are able to define ressources each step in your .gitlab-ci.yml.

We can switch to use kubernetes runner if there's option to do. Is there any examples, please.

Please edit your question so I can see your current .gitlab-ci.yml. This would help me to point you in the right direction.
